# Online game give the error "("ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] "

Tags: python, sockets, server, pygame, pickle

I made a game in python with pygame and socket, my game works perfectly in local server, but when i want to try it with my friend it give me these errors :

```
("ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

and

```
   Traceback (most recent call last
File "C:/Users/Zahraa Rached/Desktop/Poké-aim/client.py", line 54, in <module>
   game = n.send("get")
 File "C:\Users\Zahraa Rached\Desktop\Poké-aim\network.py", line 25, in send
   return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096))EOFError: Ran out of input
```

My port are frowarded and i arleady played a game that i have coded on different pc (with my friends)
so the problem should not be my server host
(i tried a lot of different things like disabling my firewall and my antivirus)

network class:

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server="my public ip"
        self.port=50
        self.addr=(self.server,self.port)
        self.p=self.connect()

    def getP(self):
        return self.p
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(4096).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self,data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))

            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

server

```
import socket
from _thread import*
import pickle
from game import*

g=Game()
clientnb=0
server="192.168.1.43"
port=50
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


try:

    s.bind((server,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)

s.listen()
print("J'attend une connexion, Dresseur de Pokémon")
def thread(conn,p):
    global clientnb
    global g
    print(clientnb)
    g.pos[p]=(0,0)

    conn.send(str.encode(str(p)))
    r=False

    reply=""
    while True:
        if g.ready == clientnb and clientnb > 1:
            g.start=True
        else:
            g.start=False
        try:
            data=conn.recv(4096).decode()
            if data=="ready":
                r=True
                g.ready+=1
            elif data=="clik":
                    print("x")
                    print(g.ball)
                    g.changepos()
                    g.changeball()
                    print(g.ball)
            elif data=="reset":
                g.reset()
            elif data=="win":
                g.end=True


            elif data!="get":

                co=eval(data)
                g.pos[p]=co

            elif not data:
                print("oh")
                if r:
                    g.ready-=1
                clientnb-=1
                del g.pos[p]
                break


            reply = g
            conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
        except:
            print("ohh")
            if r:
                g.ready -= 1
            clientnb -= 1
            g.reset()
            break
    conn.close()
while True:
    conn,addr=s.accept()
    print(addr)
    p = clientnb
    start_new_thread(thread,(conn,p))

    clientnb+=1
```

client:

```
import pygame
import pickle
import sys
from network import Network
import time
import socket
pygame.font.init()

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
run=True
timevar=False
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
myscore=0
w=1280
h=720
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Poké-Aim")
n=Network()
fond_color=(0,0,0)
color1 = (255, 0, 0)
click=pygame.mixer.Sound("click.ogg")




ball=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert_alpha(),(71,62))
master=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("master.png").convert_alpha(),(35,31))
bigmaster=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("master.png").convert_alpha(),(71,62))
cursor=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("cursor.png").convert_alpha(),(48,48))
other_cursor=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("black_cursor.png").convert_alpha(),(48,48))
playing=False
loosing=False
winning=False
def find_key(v):
    for k, val in pos.items():
        if v == val:
            return k

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

ready=False
start=False
p=int(n.getP())
print(p)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
while run:

    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill(fond_color)
    try:
        game = n.send("get")

    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)
        run=False
        print("Connexion perdue")
        break
    if game!=None:
        start=game.start
        name=game.name
        bol=game.ball
        pos=game.pos
        end=game.end
        if game.ready==0:
            ready=False
    if not start:
        if not ready:
            color1=(255,0,0)
        font = pygame.font.Font("Pokemon Classic.ttf", 20)
        sc=font.render("= 1 pts", 1,(255,255,255) )
        sc2=font.render("= 3pts", 1,(255,255,255) )
        screen.blit(sc,(w/2,150))
        screen.blit(sc2, (w / 2, 215))
        screen.blit(ball,((w/2-80),140))
        screen.blit(bigmaster, ((w / 2 - 80), 200))

        text = font.render("Clique sur l'écran pour te mettre prêt !", 1,color1 )

        screen.blit(text, ((w - text.get_width()) / 2, (h - text.get_height()) / 2))
    elif start:

        screen.fill((255,244,10))
        if not playing:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            playing=True
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                while not ready and not timevar:

                    color1 = (0,255, 0)

                    screen.blit(text, ((w - text.get_width()) / 2, (h - text.get_height()) / 2))
                    n.send("ready")
                    click.play()
                    ready=True
                if start:
                    if name=="P":
                        if (bol[0]) <= (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] ) <= (bol[0] + 71):
                            if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]>= (bol[1]) and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= (bol[1] + 62):
                                click.play()
                                n.send("clik")
                                click.play()
                                myscore+=1
                    else:
                        if (bol[0]) <= (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] ) <= (bol[0] + 35):
                            if (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]) >= (bol[1]) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] )<= (bol[1] + 31):
                                click.play()
                                n.send("clik")
                                myscore+=3

    try:
        n.client.send(str.encode(str(pygame.mouse.get_pos())))
    except :
        pass

    if start:
        if name=="P":
            screen.blit(ball, (bol[0], bol[1]))
        else:
            screen.blit(master, (bol[0], bol[1]))



        for e in pos.values():
            if find_key(e) != p:
                if find_key(e) != p:
                    screen.blit(other_cursor, (e[0]-24,e[1]-24))



    score = font.render(str(myscore), 1, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(score, (5,0))
    if myscore >= 1:

        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        wintext = font.render("T'as gagné sale bg !", 1, color1)
        screen.blit(wintext, ((w - wintext.get_width()) / 2, (h - wintext.get_height()) / 2))






        pygame.display.update()
        n.send("win")
        if not timevar:
            chrono=time.time()
            timevar=True
        if round(time.time()-chrono)>4:
            n.send("reset")

            color1 = (255, 0, 0)
            start = False
            ready = False
            playing = False
            myscore = 0
            timevar=False

            end = False
    elif end:

        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        loosetext = font.render("T'as perdu t'es trop nul sérieux !", 1, (255,0,0))
        screen.blit(loosetext, ((w - loosetext.get_width()) / 2, (h - loosetext.get_height()) / 2))

        pygame.display.update()

        if not timevar:
            chrono = time.time()
            timevar = True
        if round(time.time() - chrono) > 4:

            color1 = (255, 0, 0)
            start = False
            ready = False
            playing = False
            myscore = 0
            timevar = False

            end = False




    screen.blit(cursor,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]-24,pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]-24))
    pygame.display.update()
```

game_class:

```
import random
h=720
w=1280
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="P"
        self.pos= {}
        self.ball=[w/2,h/2]
        self.ready=0
        self.start=False
        self.end=False
    def changepos(self):
        if self.name=="P":
            self.ball[0]=random.randrange(0+71,w-71)
            self.ball[1]=random.randrange(0,h-62)
        else:
            self.ball[0] = random.randrange(0 + 35, w- 35)
            self.ball[1] = random.randrange(0, h - 31)
    def changeball(self):
        self.name=random.choice("MPPPPPPPPPP")
    def reset(self):
        self.name = "P"

        self.ball = [w / 2, h / 2]
        self.ready=0

        self.start = False
        self.end = False
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick read of [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) about `socket.recv()` tells us that `self.client.recv(4096)` uses that 4096 *buf_size* parameter as:

> The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by [...]

So, it's the *maximum*, not the minimum. Your `.recv()` will never receive more than 4096 bytes. That's all.

But the code is assuming it will always `recv()` enough bytes:

```
return pickle.loads( self.client.recv(4096) ) # gambling a crash on Rx size
```

On your current network set-up, something is causing smaller packets to arrive at the `recv()`, and not a full "pickle-worth".  This is *always* an issue with network communications, it may be temporary, it may be permanent.  Maybe a damp connection is causing packet loss, maybe maybe maybe.  It was working before because the network/computers behaved differently.

So what do you do?  The solution is check to see if any bytes have arrived.  *If* bytes have arrived, add them to an "incoming-buffer".  *If* there's enough bytes in the buffer, unpack it.

Pickling a data structure for sending over the network is probably an OK method, but I would first transmit the data-size of the pickled object, so the receiving client can know whether enough bytes have arrived to unpack it.  Sure you can `try..catch` the un-pickling, but that's grossly inefficient.

I would use `struct.pack` to send the pickle-buffer size as a 4-byte integer (in network-byte order).  Receive those 4 bytes first, then wait for the further *N* bytes to arrive.

**EDIT: More details on struct, etc.**

```
import struct
import pickle

def sendData( server_sock, object ):
    result = True
    data = pickle.dumps( object )
    data_size = struct.pack( '!I', len( data ) )  # good for 2^32 bytes

    try:
        server_sock.sendall( data_size )   # send the size of the pickled obj
        server_sock.sendall( data )        # send the obj
    except:
        sys.stderr.write( "Error sending data to server\n" )
        result = False
    return result
```

And then to receive the data, read the 4-byte size field and then the pickle data.  Something like the below should work (note: this is not tested code, I'm just answering off the top of my head)

```
def recvData( client_sock ):
    """ Try to receive a picked data-structure from the socket.
        Returns True and an unpicked object, or False and None   """
    result   = False
    packet   = None
    expected = -1

    # First we read a 4-byte pickle size, and following that is /N/ bytes
    # of pickled structure data.

    # Read the 4-byte packet size first
    buffer = bytes()
    while ( len( buffer ) < 4 ):
        try:
            some_data = client_sock.recv( 4 - len( buffer ) )
            if ( some_data ):
                 buffer.append( some_data )
                 if ( len( buffer ) == 4 ):
                     expected = struct.unpack( '!I', buffer )
        except:
            # TODO: work out which sort of exceptions are OK
            break

    # If we received a buffer size, try to receive the buffer
    if ( expected > 0 ):
        buffer = bytes()
        while ( len( buffer ) < expected ): 
            try:
                some_data = client_sock.recv( expected - len( buffer ) )
                if ( some_data ):
                     buffer.append( some_data )
                     # Have we received the full data-set yet?
                     if ( len( buffer ) == expected ):
                         packet = pickle.loads( buffer )
                         result = True   # success
        except:
            # TODO: work out which sort of exceptions are OK
            break

     return result, packet
```

To be honest if you're just sending fixed amounts all the time (like a pair of x/y co-ordinates), it might be easier to just pack and unpack everything, using fixed-size datagrams.  Maybe that's not "pythonic" enough though ;)

Anyway, what makes good network code is handling all the little rough edges.  Sometimes (for a hundred different reasons), data does not arrive in nicely sized blocks, or your network blocks for a second or so.  Simply handling this with a buffer, and non-blocking code solves 99% of the ills.

Really the `recv()` above should be non-blocking code, but this is left as an exercise for the reader.  I like to use `select()` for this, but that's a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: thank you i understand what is the issue , i made search on struct, but i still have no idea how to really do this , should i send the 4 bytes from the server before or after sending the game class ? and how do i get the pickle buffer-size of the pickle that the server is sending , sorry if it's sumb question i'm really new to programming and especially on network

Comment: i tired this code , it work on localhost with a lot of latency between the client , and after 50 second it gives me [WinError 10054] , on two different pc it give me the previous error [WinError 10053] my code : https://paste.pythondiscord.com/mebexenugo.py

Comment: @Epini - Did you search on that error code?  There's lots of explanations.  The remote host has closed the connection.  So it's a problem in the server code.

Comment: i think i found out the problem , in my game i need to update the cursor of the opponent every second and update it on the screen, but if we check each time if the correct number of bytes arrived it's creat too much latency ( like 7sec) , i think that my game is too hard , to make it "online" , but thank you for your help