# Python - [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - sending pickled data issues

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pygame

I followed an online tutorial that showed how to make a rock paper scissors game that can handle multiple clients connecting to a server, allowing multiplayer. The game works so I tried to use the same network logic for a different game but I ran into some errors there. Particularly when using the `send` function: Using the `send` function I get an `EOFError: Ran out of input` error. In this post [Online game give the error "("ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361900/online-game-give-the-error-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053) I found a supposed fix where the send function waits until it has received all of the data, as it sometimes may have issues when receiving pickled data.

However, when I replace the `send` function with the new `send2` function (temporary name) I run into different errors. Namely: `[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

SOLVED, SEE FOLLOWING PARAGRAPh:

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is replacing my send function (which also receives data) by a better send function that sends pickled data and receives the exact amount of sent information.

```
def send(self, data):
    try:
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)

# source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361900/online-game-give-the-error-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053
def send2(self, data):
    data_to_send = pickle.dumps(data)
    data_size = struct.pack( '!I', len(data_to_send))
    try:
        self.client.send(data_size)
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        
        package = self.receive()
        return package
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)

        
def receive(self):
    packet = None
    buffer = bytes()
    expected = -1
    print("receiving stuff")
    while len(buffer) < 4:
        print("received a buffer")
        try:
            partial_data = self.client.recv(4 - len(buffer))
            if partial_data:
                 buffer.append(partial_data)
                 if len(buffer) == 4:
                     expected = struct.unpack('!I', buffer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break

    # If we received a buffer size, try to receive the buffer
    if expected > 0:
        buffer = bytes()
        while len(buffer) < expected: 
            try:
                partial_data = self.client.recv(expected - len(buffer))
                if partial_data:
                     buffer.append(partial_data)
                     # Have we received the full data-set yet?
                     if len(buffer) == expected:
                         packet = pickle.loads(buffer)
            except:
                break
            
    print(packet)
    return packet
```

I'm assuming I'm overlooking something incredibly easy. If needed, I can post the 4 .py files that run the game. All I need is to create a better `send` function that doesn't crash the client when it is dealing with sending data that is sometimes not pickle-worthy.

EDIT:

Server.py code

```
import socket
import pickle
from _thread import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Program Files/Hero Realms/Multiplayer/")
from game import Game
from network import Network

server = "" # this is defined but I removed it for this page
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
    
s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")

connected = set()
games = {}
id_count = 0

def threadedClient(conn, p, game_id):
    global id_count 
    conn.send(str.encode(str(p)))
    
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            #data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(4096))
            data = Network.receive(s)
            print(data)
            # check if the game still exists
            if game_id in games:
                game = games[game_id]
                
                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    if data == "reset":
                        game.resetWent()
                    elif data != "get":
                        game.play(p, data)
                        
                    reply = game
                    conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
                    
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
        
    print("Lost connection")
    
    try:
        print("Closing game", game_id)
        del games[game_id]
    except:
        pass
    
    id_count -=1
    conn.close()
    
    
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)
    
    id_count += 1
    p = 0
    game_id = (id_count - 1) // 2
    
    if id_count % 2 == 1:
        games[game_id] = Game(game_id)
        print("Creating a new game...")
    else:
        games[game_id].ready = True
        p = 1
        
    
    start_new_thread(threadedClient, (conn, p, game_id))
```

Client.py

```
import pygame

import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Program Files/Hero Realms/Multiplayer/")
from network import Network
import pickle

pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()

width = 700
height = 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.width = 150
        self.height = 100
        
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
        win.blit(text, (self.x + round(self.width / 2) - round(text.get_width() / 2), self.y + round(self.height / 2) - round(text.get_height() / 2)))
        
    def click(self, pos):
        x1 = pos[0]
        y1 = pos[1]
        
        if self.x <= x1 <= self.x + self.width and self.y <= y1 <= self.y + self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
def redrawWindow(win, game, p):
    win.fill((128, 128, 128))
    
    if not(game.connected()):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 80)
        text = font.render("Waiting for Player...", 1, (255, 0, 0), True)
        win.blit(text, (width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))
    else:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)
        text = font.render("Your Move", 1, (0, 255, 255))
        win.blit(text, (80, 200))
        
        text = font.render("Opponents", 1, (0, 255, 255))
        win.blit(text, (380, 200))
        
        move1 = game.getPlayersMove(0)
        move2 = game.getPlayersMove(1)
        if game.bothWent():
            text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0, 0, 0))
        else:
            if game.p1_went and p == 0:
                text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            elif game.p1_went:
                text1 = font.render("Locked in", 1, (0, 0, 0))
            else:
                text1 = font.render("Waiting...", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                
            if game.p2_went and p == 1:
                text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            elif game.p2_went:
                text2 = font.render("Locked in", 1, (0, 0, 0))
            else:
                text2 = font.render("Waiting...", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                
        if p == 1:
            win.blit(text2, (100, 350))
            win.blit(text1, (400, 350))
        else:
            win.blit(text1, (100, 350))
            win.blit(text2, (400, 350))
                
        for btn in btns:
            btn.draw(win)
            
    pygame.display.update()
        
        
        

    
    
    
btns = [Button("Rock", 50, 500, (0, 0, 0)), Button("Scissors",  250, 500, (255, 0, 0)), Button("Paper", 450, 500, (0, 255, 0))]


def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    n = Network()
    player = int(n.getP())
    print("You are player ", player)
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        try:
            game = n.send2("get")
        except:
            run = False
            print("Couldn't get game")
            break
        
        if game.bothWent():
            redrawWindow(win, game, player)
            pygame.time.delay(500)
            try:
                game = n.send2("reset")
            except:
                run = False
                print("Couldn't get game")
                break
            
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 90)
            if (game.winner() == 1 and player == 1) or (game.winner() == 0 and player == 0):
                text = font.render("You won!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
            elif game.winner() == -1:
                text = font.render("Tie game!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
            else:
                text = font.render("You lost", 1, (255, 0, 0))
                
            win.blit(text, (width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(2000)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for btn in btns:
                    if btn.click(pos) and game.connected():
                        if player == 0:
                            if not game.p1_went:
                                n.send2(btn.text)
                        else:
                            if not game.p2_went:
                                n.send2(btn.text)
                                
        redrawWindow(win, game, player)
                        
def menuScreen():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        win.fill((128, 128, 128))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)
        text = font.render("Click to play!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
        win.blit(text, (100, 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                run = False
                
    main()
    
while True:
    menuScreen()
```

Comment: Without seeing the server code it's hard to know what the problem is. Also, you haven't specified the line that is causing the exception to be raised. Finally, your `receive()` method has some severe bugs. A `bytes()` object does not have an `append()` method, and is in fact immutable. If you want a mutable version, use a `bytearray()`. Even then, you would use the `extend()` method, not the `append()` method.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I added the server code. I did not know the remarks regarding the bytes() object, I followed the code from one of the proposed solutions that is linked to this post.

Comment: The code in that answer was entered off the top of the author's head. He stated he hadn't even run the code. It is best to view it as python-ish pseudo-code rather working code.

Comment: That is true. Though his code does work, it is able to send data and receive data. However, since sending and receiving is looped in the client I get this error : `WinError 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` after the first iteration. I added the client file as well.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I managed to fix my own errors and added the fix to the post. In the end it was difficult finding what exactly caused my errors and where those errors came from. Therefore, I started from scratch and found a solution to my original problem: coding a function that sends X pickled data and a function that receives exactly X pickled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to finally accomplish what I wanted to do in the first place. I wanted to write a send function that sent out X amount of pickled data alongside a receive function that received X amount of pickled data without throwing errors when it received data that was too small to be pickled.

See the `send_data` and the `receive_data` functions for the solution in `network.py`. The server file `server.py` requires these functions as well although slightly different. In your client file you should thus make use of the `network.send_data` function to send data from the client to the server.

`network.py`

```
import socket
import pickle
HEADERSIZE = 10

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "enter server address"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.p = self.connect()
        
    def getP(self):
        return self.p
    
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    # works but only sends and receives string encoded data without a buffer
    def send1(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
            
    # works but only sends and receives pickled data without a buffer
    def send2(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
        
    # this is the function you should use, it uses a receive function that has a buffer
    # and ensures that you receive ALL the information that you sent without throwing errors
    def send_data(self, data):
        data_to_send = pickle.dumps(data)
        data_size = bytes(f'{len(data_to_send):<{10}}', "utf-8")
        try:
            self.client.send(data_size + data_to_send)
            
            package = self.receive_data()
            return package
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
    
    def receive_data(self):
        full_msg = b''
        new_msg = True
        while True:
            msg = self.client.recv(16)
            if new_msg:
                msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
                new_msg = False
                
            full_msg += msg
    
            if len(full_msg)-HEADERSIZE == msglen:
                data = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
                break
    
        return data
```

`server.py`

```
import socket
import pickle
from _thread import *
import sys
from game import Game

server = "enter server address"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
    
s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")

connected = set()
games = {}
id_count = 0
HEADERSIZE = 10

def receive_data(sock):
    full_msg = b''
    new_msg = True
    while True:
        msg = sock.recv(16)
        if new_msg:
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new_msg = False

        full_msg += msg

        if len(full_msg)-HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            data = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            break

    return data

def send_data(clientsocket, data):
    data_to_send = pickle.dumps(data)
    data_size = bytes(f'{len(data_to_send):<{10}}', "utf-8")
    try:
        clientsocket.send(data_size + data_to_send)
        
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)

def threadedClient(conn, p, game_id):
    global id_count 
    conn.send(str.encode(str(p)))
    
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = receive_data(conn)
            # check if the game still exists
            if game_id in games:
                game = games[game_id]
                
                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    if data == "reset":
                        game.resetWent()
                    elif data != "get":
                        game.play(p, data)
                        
                    reply = game
                    
                    send_data(conn, reply)

            else:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed try")
            print(e)
            break
        
    print("Lost connection")
    
    try:
        print("Closing game", game_id)
        del games[game_id]
    except:
        pass
    
    id_count -=1
    conn.close()
    
    
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)
    
    id_count += 1
    p = 0
    game_id = (id_count - 1) // 2
    
    if id_count % 2 == 1:
        games[game_id] = Game(game_id)
        print("Creating a new game...")
    else:
        games[game_id].ready = True
        p = 1
        
    
    start_new_thread(threadedClient, (conn, p, game_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by disabling the firewal for incomming connections for python.